# How to sort and update a values based on the date in table?

Tags: sql

I need your help. I want to sort values in column and then save changes. But I don't know how to do that.
Table looks like that:

```
   Date      |    DocNumber  
-----------------------------    
    2018-15-04 |        1              
    2018-15-07 |        2              
    2018-15-08 |        3              
    2018-15-06 |        4              
    2018-15-05 |        5
```

I want to get something like that:

```
     Date      |    DocNumber  
-----------------------------    
2018-15-04      |    1     
2018-15-05      |    2     
2018-15-06      |    3    
2018-15-07      |    4    
2018-15-08      |    5
```

So I need to sort " DocNumber  " and "Date" columns.
Please, help.

Comment: Why would you be hanging the values in each row?  The question doesn't really make sense.  You should also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Sorting values independently in each column is not really recommended.  However, it can be done.  Here is one method:

```
select max(date) as date, max(docnumber) as docnumber
from ((select row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum, date, NULL as docnumber
       from t
      ) union all
      (select row_number() over (order by docnumber) as seqnum, NULL, docnumber
       from t
      )
     ) dd
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```